# Good search solution for Zend Framework + Doctrine + MySQL?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, search, doctrine, zend-search-lucene

I've looked into Doctrine's built-in search, MySQL myisam fulltext search, Zend_Lucene, and sphinx - but all the nuances and implementation details are making it hard to sort out for me, given that I don't have experience with anything other than the myisam search.

What I really want is something simple that will work with the Zend Framework and Doctrine (MySQL back-end, probably InnoDB).  I don't need complex things like word substitutions, auto-complete, and so on (not that I'd be opposed to such things, if it were easy enough and time effective enough to implement).

The main thing is the ability to search for strings across multiple database tables, and multiple fields with some basic search criteria (e.g. `user.state. = CA AND user.active = 1`).  The size of the database will start at around 50K+ records (old data being dumped in), the biggest single searchable table would be around 15K records, and it would grow considerably over time.

That said, Zend_Lucene is appealing to me because it is flexible (in case I do need my search solution to gorw in the future) and because it can parse MS Office files (which will be uploaded to my application by users).  But its flexibility also makes it kind of complicated to set up.

I suppose the most straightforward option would be to just use Doctrine's search capabilities, but I'm not sure if that's going to be able to handle what I need.  And I don't know that there is any option out there which is going to combine my desire for simplicity & power.

What search solutions would you recommend I investigate?  And why would you think that solution would work well in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment using [**Solr**](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html) search engine.

**Solr** is an open source enterprise search server based on the Lucene Java search library, with XML/HTTP and JSON APIs, hit highlighting, faceted search, caching, replication, a web **administration interface (which is really great)** and many more features.

It runs in a Java servlet container such as Tomcat.

You can use the [**solr-php-client**](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/wiki/ExampleUsage) to handle queries in php.